# Gradle NativeExecutable from linked libs only

Tags: c++, gradle, makefile, native

I'm trying to create two native executables using `gradle`. The code is written in cpp and so far the process was being done using a makefile.

I have an issue though when trying to create the executables since they do not have any source code themselves but are being created simply from linking some other libs.

Take a look at the line in the makefile that produces the executables to better understand:

```
link.exe <linker flags> lib1.obj lib2.obj lib3.obj /out:my_executable_1.exe
link.exe <linker flags> lib1.obj lib4.obj /out:my_executable_2.exe
```

In gradle now I have done the following:

```
model {

    components {

        lib1(NativeLibrarySpec) {}

        lib2(NativeLibrarySpec) {}

        lib3(NativeLibrarySpec) {}

        lib4(NativeLibrarySpec) {}

        my_executable_1(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    lib library: 'lib1', linkage: 'static'
                    lib library: 'lib2', linkage: 'static'
                    lib library: 'lib3', linkage: 'static'
                }
            }
        }

       my_executable_2(NativeExecutableSpec) {
           sources {
               cpp {
                    lib library: 'lib1', linkage: 'static'
                    lib library: 'lib4', linkage: 'static'
                }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

When I'm running the my_executable_1Executable task, the static libraries are being created correctly but I get no executable as output since it always shows:

```
:linkMy_executable_1Executable UP-TO-DATE
:my_executable_1Executable UP-TO-DATE
```

Anyone knows how to make this work? Do I have to specify anything special in the gradle configuration?

I must admit the documentation did not help me that much in this specific case.

Comment: I found one way around but it requires creating a dummy cpp file under the `my_executable_1/cpp` and `my_executable_2/cpp`  directories. Simply by creating a file with no code inside it, makes the executables be created. I would like to avoid this as well though since it seems weird and fragile.

Comment: I would guess that Gradle doesn't find any `inputs` for the linking task, and so skips it. A task with no inputs is, by definition, always considered up-to-date. Your workaround jumps this hurdle in a sort of hackish way, but it should at least work consistently if that is the cause. Do you see anything interesting when you run `gradle components`?

Comment: Nothing unusual to be honest. Similar to any other libs/executables I have.

Answer (score 0):

I am in pretty much the same situation, except that I try to build shared libraries from a set of static libraries. I work with gradle 2.10.

I can confirm that gradle links the binaries with the 'dummy cpp file' in the corresponding source set, but this is a ugly hack and I think this should work right away without any problems. (as easy as it is with a make file...)

Comment: Please don't post confirmation or comments as an answer, post them as comments. Answers should be reserved for when you know what solves the problem.

Comment: I'd love to but "You must have 50 reputation to comment" appears, when i click on some "add a comment" links.